# How to make a branch from the commit previous to a merge?

Tags: git, merge

I'm using `gitflow` workflow. From `master`, I created a `hotfix` branch and did some fix. Before merging back to `master`, I figured I'd merge to `develop` first, just to see the changes in staging and then merge to master.

Said merge to `develop` fix had a conflict that I solved by merging develop into the `hotfix` branch (yes, shame on me) and I just realized I can't merge that to `master`, as develop have unstable things yet.

How do I create a branch from the commit previous to the merge with develop?

PS: I merged using `git merge develop` (didn't use the `no-ff` flag).

Comment: Do you need a branch or do you just need to merge that commit into master?

Comment: A branch because our repository rule is no direct push to master, always PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your structure looks something like this:

```
A - B - C        <- master
 \   \
  \   \- F - G   <- hotfix
   \       /
    \-D - E      <- dev
```

You would like to merge the commit represented by `F` back into `master`, which is now at `C`.

You can create a separate branch to do this, as you request:

```
git checkout hotfix^ -b unmerged-hotfix
```

In this case `hotfix^` is the commit before the current tip of `hotfix`. The new branch will be called `unmerged-hotfix`.

If on the other hand you just want to merge directly into master without making a new branch, you can do

```
git checkout master
git merge hotfix^
```

This will merge the commit before the tip of `hotfix` into master.

Comment: Excellent explanation. In my case I wanted a new branch because we can't push to master (repo rule) so we always open a PR. Now, suppose I did a `H `and `I` commit on `hotfix` after merging `develop`.  How would I achieve the same results, but **with** `H` and `I` on `master`? (basically, every commit, except for the merge: `F`, `H`, `I`; but no `G`)

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco. I would do an interactive rebase or a cherry-pick. This is completely outside the scope of your current question though, so I would go ahead and ask another one. If you needed a PR, I would basically branch off from `F` as described here, then cherry-pick or rebase `H` and `I` onto that.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Alternatively, you can edit your post with the extended question as part of a more detailed explanation of what you want to do, and I will expand my answer accordingly. Given the question you have, I don't think that would make it too broad or anything.